# While running my Spring boot project with Azure SQL server connection and getting error like Unsupported Database: Microsoft SQL Server 12.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure

While running Spring boot project getting error as below. We are using Azure sql server 12 and able to connect SQL database from my local. I am using same database details in my local of the    properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx.database.windows.net:1433;database=xxxxx
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx



 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
 error:

  Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Unsupported Database: Microsoft SQL Server 12.0

 Any idea?

 Able to connect Azure SQL database from my local and showing version 12.X
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to add another dependency for flyway to work with this database:

https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/sql-server-184127608.html

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-sqlserver</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thanks and solved by adding this dependency

Comment: so please, can you mark the answer as accepted to show others that it helped and it's the correct one?